# L'Hospital's Rule for a fraction where the numerator clearly grows faster than the denominator

Tags: calculus, limits

According to L'Hospital's Rule, the limit as x approaches infinity of $\frac{8x+5}{6x}$ is simply the derivative of the numerator over the derivative of the denominator is simply $8/6$. 
I don't understand why it is $8/6$. $8x+5$ clearly grows faster than $6x$, so shouldn't the limit be infinity?

Comment: You are right. Your computation tells you it grows $8/6$ faster. Compare that to what would happen to $\frac{8x^2+5}{6x}$. The growth would be the same as $\frac{8}{6}x$, which does go to infinity.

Comment: The important thing here is that their growth is **of the same order**.

Comment: This may be the lamest application of L'Hopital in the long history of lame applications of L'Hopital: $\frac{8x+5}{6x}=\frac86+\frac5{6x}$.

Comment: With your reasoning, $2 = \frac {2x}{x} \to \infty$

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich It is certainly faster than what you did. I find lamer working more for the same yield.

Comment: @sunwarm: I think adding fractions or splitting them into two parts is far easier (available to seventh graders) than the process of differentiation. At the same time the rule fails miserably if one replaces numerator $8x$ by $8x+\sin x$ and the splitting works fine.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh You think wrong, plus the process of differentiation of polynomials is also available to anyone that can multiply and add, the same operations needed for long division, only fewer.

Comment: @sunwarm: Ok, but when I was studying fractions (as well as operations on polynomials) I had no idea of differentiation. Anyway as long as one can avoid the pitfalls of this infamous rule, it is fine to use it.

Comment: @OP, $8x + 5$ grows $8/6$ times faster than $6x$, which is why the answer is $8/6$.

Answer (score 2):

1. ‘Grows faster’ doesn't means ‘grows infinitely faster’; i.e. if you know some *asymptotic analysis*, it doesn't mean, here, that $6x=o(8xx+5$. Actually, $6x=O(8x+5$.
2. Stop thinking  that L'Hospital's rule is the ultimate way to limits: it is actually a dangerous rule, as it requires some hypotheses that most people never check. Anyway, when it works, it is equivalent to Taylor's formula at order $1$.
3. It is a high-school theorem that the limit at infinity of a rational function is just the limit of the ratio of the leading terms of its numerator and denominator, so that all you have to say here is this:
   $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{8x+5}{6x}=\lim _{x\to\infty}\frac{8\not x}{6\not x}=\frac 43.$$

Answer (score 0):

Without Using L'hopital
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{8x+5}{6x}=
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{8+5x^{-1}}{6}=\frac{8}{6}
$$
as $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{-1}=0$.